# Git - Resolving a merge conflict in a word document

Tags: git, bitbucket

```
On branch test
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   Git Basics.docx

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I am trying to merge a file from branch `develop` into branch `test`. Usually I do not have a problem with this but it's the first time I am working with a conflict arising in a Word Document.

The following link was helpful for my initial understanding on how to resolve merge conflicts - https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/

From the link, I am expecting to see something like:

```
If you have questions, please
<<<<<<< HEAD
open an issue
=======
ask your question in IRC.
>>>>>>> branch-a
```

which tells me where and what the conflict is. But I cannot view this on the Word Document.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: That kind of conflict resolution only works for pure text files. Word files are not pure text files, you will need a merge tool that can handle Word files for this.

Comment: Don't store DOCX files in git, but you can store their unzipped contents which is XML. Then you'll be able to see the differences.

Comment: Appreciate the comments, but in my current state what must I do to resolve this?

Comment: The only thing you can do with binary files is to consider one of the versions as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, set up your default merge tool for git. There are numerous options available. Personally, meld has been my favorite. Download and install meld from the internet. Now open your global .gitconfig file. At the end of this file, add the following lines-

```
[mergetool]
  prompt = false
[mergetool "meld"]
  trustExitCode = true
  cmd = open -W -a Meld --args --auto-merge \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$BASE\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\" --output=\"$PWD/$MERGED\"
```

Please note that the "cmd =" is a command to open meld. Its path should be different on your machine.

Once the meld tool is set up, and when you are in middle of resolving a merge conflict, type this on console-

```
$ git mergetool
```

This command will open your default merge tool (meld in this case) and will allow you a three paneled UI, representing local/current/remote versions of a file which is in conflict. You can choose the right changes you want from there. Save the file once you think that the merge is complete. Git will ask you if the merge was correct. Hit Y if it was, N otherwise. Git moves to the next conflict in case of yes and the process continues.